# Add metadata to WSGIRequest object

Tags: python, django, session, middleware, requestcontext

I have Django1.9 middleware class:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        token = self._get_or_create_token(request)
        #request.context['token'] = token
```

The issue is:
- I would like to put token to some sort of context to pass it through the application flow.
- I avoid putting it into request session, because it result in extra database reading/writing.

Could you suggest me some solution?

Comment: Just add the attribute to the request, so `request.token = token`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add any attribute to the `HttpRequest`, so you can implement this with:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        token = self._get_or_create_token(request)
        request.token = token
```

or if you really want some sort of `context` dictionary:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        token = self._get_or_create_token(request)
        if not hasattr(request, 'context'):
            request.context = {}
        request.context['token'] = token
```

> I have Django1.9 middleware class.

As is [documented](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/), [django-1.9](/questions/tagged/django-1.9) is not supported anymore since **April 2017**, therefore I strongly advice to update.